# Redirect users to a new page with ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to ASP.
In my current project I want to add a banner and by clicking on the banner we are showing a page which has login and new user options.
If the user is new, then clicking on the NewUser link redirects to a registration page which I already have in the project, and creates a user.
After registration I want to redirect the same user to a page (ex. xyz.asp).

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You can redirect a user with [Response.Redirect](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_redirect.asp).

Examples

If you want to send them to page in the same folder:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "xyz.asp"
%>
```

If you want to send them to page in the parent folder:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "../xyz.asp"
%>
```

If you want to send them to page on a differect site:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "http://www.example.com/"
%>
```